# WebStorm tool for showing CSS attributes definitions

Tags: css, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm IDE for developing my web apps. I was wondering if there is any tool for showing CSS's attribute definitions while hovering on attribute. I saw in VSCode, is there any for WebStorm? If so, how to enable it?

Example

[image]

Comment: "View | Quick Documentation" (`Ctrl+Q` on Windows) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar popup is available on **View | Quick Documentation** (`Ctrl+Q`):

[image]

You can enable **Show quick documentation on mouse move** in **Settings | Editor | Code Editing** to see the docs on mouse hover